# Arista Transcode turns subtitle to gibberish

Tags: video, subtitle

This has recently happened to me. In Arista Transcode 0.9.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 the burnt subtitle ( a persian `.srt` encoded in UTF-8) turns into gibberish after a few minutes.

I have tried different video formats but none worked with Arista. When I burn the srt file into video using `mencoder` command, it burns correctly. So I suspect something is wrong with Arista.

Any help to fix this Arista problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was not Arista's fault. When I re-encoded the srt file in UTF-8 (using an online encoding service) the problem was gone. So apparently for some reason some of the strings were not properly encoded in UTF-8.